# How to solve it when there are multiple SQL Server instances, but can only connect to one?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008r2-express

Using SQL Server 2008 R2

I have 2 SQL Server instances on my PC, `SQL1` and `SQL2`.

I have Windows XP installed in a VirtualBox. In XP, I have an application which can connect to SQL Servers.

When I try to connect to `SQL1`, everything is fine, but when I try to do that with `SQL2` it errors out with

> Could not open a connection to SQL Server

So I started checking the settings. I can connect to `SQL2` using SQL Server Management Studio (on a local PC), so I checked that 'Allow remote connections to this server' was enabled. Also, in SQL Server configuration tool I enabled all protocols for this instance, just as it is for the `SQL1`. SQL Server browser is working.

Configuration of both instances seem to be identical. There is only one difference between `SQL1` and `SQL2` that I have noticed.

- `SQL1` version is 10.50.4000
- `SQL2` version is 10.50.1600

What can cause one of the instances to be unreachable through the network while the other one can be, and both settings are the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be firewall settings or network settings. For an instance to be reachable, configure at least the following.

- TCP protocol enabled (SQL Server Configuration Manager)
- Fixed TCP port (SQL Server Configuration Manager)
- Enable SQL Server Browser Service
- Open firewall for SQL Browser service (UDP port 1434) if you have a named instance.
- Open TCP ports for SQL Server Instances.

See [Configure the Windows Firewall to Allow SQL Server Access](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646023.aspx)

Comment: At first i thought firewall was not an issue, because SQL1 could be connected to and i did nothing special about it to make it happen. But it does turn out that firewall was blocking the SQL2 instance. I have opened the port now and it works.